# Using the iPhone SDK, can you change the color of the disclosure accessory for a table view?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to change the color of the disclosure accessory (the arrow on the right side of a table view)?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you need to do is create your own (I use a graphic file in a UIImageView) and put it in your UITableViewCell's accessory view.